# Wordpress add <p> tags to my javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I use philantrophy theme, in which I added sliders via shortcodes in a page then it automatically inserted p tags inside my javascript.

below code shows p tag added in my javascript code:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    jQuery('.main-slider, .page-header').prepend('<img src="http://localhost/projects/new_site/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/sketch.png" alt="" id="testimage" class="hidden">');
});</p>
<p>    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {</p>
<p>        jQuery('.main-carousel').prepend('<img src="http://localhost/projects/new_site/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/sketch.png" alt="" class="testimage hidden">');</p>
<p>        jQuery('.testimage').load(function(){
        jQuery(".slider-full .spinner, .slider-full .testimage").remove();
        jQuery(".main-carousel").removeClass('invisible').addClass('animated fadeIn');
    });</p>
<p>        var slider = jQuery('#myCarousel'),
                        animateClass;</p>
<p>        //Brogressbar Slider
        var percent = 0, bar = jQuery('.brogressbar'), interval = 2;</p>
<p>        function progressBarCarousel() {
                bar.css({width:percent+'%'});
                bar.css('transition', '0.2s');
                percent = percent +1;</p>
<p>        }
        var barInterval = setInterval(progressBarCarousel, interval/105);
        slider.carousel({
                interval: interval,
                pause: false
        }).on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
                            percent=0;
                            bar.css('transition', '0s')
                    });</p>
<p>        slider.find('[data-animate-in]').addClass('animated');</p>
<p>        function animateSlide() {
                slider.find('.item').removeClass('current');</p>
<p>                slider.find('.active').addClass('current').find('[data-animate-in]').each(function () {
                        var $this = jQuery(this);
                        animateClass = $this.data('animate-in');
                        $this.addClass(animateClass);
                });</p>
<p>                slider.find('.active').find('[data-animate-out]').each(function () {
                        var $this = jQuery(this);
                        animateClass = $this.data('animate-out');
                        $this.removeClass(animateClass);
                });
        }
        function animateSlideEnd() {
            slider.find('.active [data-animate-in], .carousel-indicators, .carousel-control').each(function () {
                    var $this = jQuery(this);
                    animateClass = $this.data('animate-in');
                    $this.removeClass(animateClass);
            });
            slider.find('.active [data-animate-in], .carousel-indicators, .carousel-control').each(function () {
                    var $this = jQuery(this);
                    animateClass = $this.data('animate-out');
                    $this.addClass(animateClass);
            });
        }</p>
<p>        slider.find('.invisible').removeClass('invisible');
        animateSlide();</p>
<p>        slider.on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
                animateSlide();
        });
        slider.on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
                animateSlideEnd();
        });</p>
<p>        if (Modernizr.touch) {
            slider.find('.carousel-inner').swipe( {
                    swipeLeft: function() {
                        jQuery(this).parent().carousel('prev');
                    },
                    swipeRight: function() {
                        jQuery(this).parent().carousel('next');
                    },
                    threshold: 30
            });
        }
    });</p>
<p></script>
```

I also tried

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

inside theme's function.php
Please help me out to get rid of this. thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you output your html with `the_content();` ? If yes try to do `echo get_the_content();` in place.

Comment: in which file should i do this? @DFayet

Comment: Where are you putting this script? On the page editor directly?

Comment: Mmh, I'm not sure my solution was the right one except if you only have shortcode in your page, and if you have a specific template for this page. Do you create the shortcode yourself?

Comment: This script is already in one of my theme files

Comment: no I didn't create any shortcodes. its already there in philantrophy theme. I just used it

Comment: What do you mean by "This script is already in one of my theme files"?

Comment: the above posted script is in template.php file

Comment: Just an idea, does it work to wrap the script in html comment <!-- or use cdata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options,

1. Take all the whitespace out of the script so that WordPress does not add `<p>` tags.
2. Check out this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

> The safe and recommended method of adding JavaScript to a WordPress generated page, and WordPress Theme or Plugin, is by using wp_enqueue_script(). This function includes the script if it hasn't already been included, and safely handles dependencies.

As stated here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

> This is the recommended method of linking JavaScript to a WordPress generated page.

Copy and save your script in a new file and copy it's directory.

**Example Usage**

`wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );`

**Link a Theme Script Which Depends on jQuery**

`wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', array( 'jquery' ));`

Answer (score 1):

I see its an old question, but I ran into it quite recently. I got it working without any plugins using the following approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

your code

//]]>
</script>
```

Live example (2nd code listing): [JavaScript in Beitrag einbetten](https://blog.doubleslash.de/its-frontendfriday-wordpress-javascript-in-beitrag-einbetten/). Not sure if it is working for all wordpress versions - worth a try I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick you could bypass the plugin installation if you do not have that ability.

1. Minify your JavaScript Code into one line. You can use any JS minifier available online.
2. Paste that on your page while like {minified code} to make sure everything is on one line.

Now even if the paragraph tag is added, it does not matter as the script would still execute.